# Open second PDF file with hyperlink in first PDF file

Tags: pdf, preview, pages

I have two PDF files:

- First PDF file has a content page
- Second PDF is the relative data (30 pages)

My requirement is to be able to click on the first PDF document, on a hyperlink for it to be open in the second PDF file on a certain page and certain location on that page. (Page 15 half way on that specific page)

Bare in mind I am not using a server and everything will be done locally.

Comment: Isn't this possible using an anchor in the second pdf? Sonething like heading2#section2 in the first pdf file?

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use Acrobat to add the links. When manually adding links, you specify the view to which the link points. With that, you can set the exact place where the linked to document opens.

If you have suitable software to create your "second" document, you can use Named Destinations, which can be used as target for the link.